# Why using diamond operator fails in Outer<String>.Inner obj2 = new Outer<>().new Inner() ? While same with Inner is OK?

Tags: java, generics, diamond-operator

Why using diamond operator when instanting generic Outer class (together with Inner class) gives error in Snippet 2, while snippet 1 is perfectly fine ?

I know that rare types are prohibited, but my case is not rare types - in rare types both Outer and Inner are generic, but one of them (either one) is used as raw, and the other as generic.

Snippet 1:

```
class Outer {
    class Inner<T> {

    }
}

class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer.Inner obj1 = new Outer().new Inner<>(); // fine !
        Outer.Inner<String> obj2 = new Outer().new Inner<>(); // fine !

    }
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
class Outer<T> {
    class Inner {

    }    
}

class Driver {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer.Inner obj1 = new Outer<>().new Inner();  // fine !
        Outer<String>.Inner obj2 = new Outer<>().new Inner(); // error !

    }
}
```

P.S.  Tested on Eclipse compiler.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure here (would have to dig into the spec) but I'd assume that's because of the execution order and type inference having a problem here. What I mean is that type inference sees the type of `obj2` to be `Inner` and _maybe_ even the outer type `Outer<String>` but since it first needs to create an instance of `Outer` which is _not_ an instance of `Inner` inference fails. Generally type inference over multiple levels of code (can be method calls too) has been improved with each Java version but probably is still far from perfect.

Comment: WHy would you write this code in the first place? If you don't care about the instantition of the outer class, why use an inner class at all?

Comment: @EJP I don't understand how you inferred that the OP didn't care about the instantiation of the outer class. In `Outer<String>.Inner obj2 = new Outer<>().new Inner();` it looks like he specifically wants the outer class to be an `Outer<String>`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException but why would you use an inner class if you don't need the outer class instance (it is instanciate and then forgotten). This seems to be a badly design in the first place.

Comment: @AxelH it probably is a bad design, but probably was contrived in order to phrase the question. It may also be that normally Inner does indeed use the instance of Outer, and nomally gets instantiated from an Outer instance that is kept. But this also allows expressions like this one. Note that the Outer instance is still available (to methods of class Inner) for at least as long as the Inner instance exists, and methods of inner can do things with the Outer instance, even passing a reference outside of the class.

Comment: @CodeComplete, it would be useful to add the error message you get :) Specifically, when I ran it: `error: incompatible types: Outer<Object>.Inner cannot be converted to Outer<String>.Inner`

Comment: I agree with you @DodgyCodeException , but I guess instanciate `Inner` from an instance of `Outer<String> o` would work (if I understood your answer completely), so to me this problem should not be one (even if this is allowed) since you should not have to instance a class like `Inner` without keep the instance `Outer`, if this is needed, `Inner` should not be a inner class. At least, this is my standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the diamond operator to infer the type parameter:

```
Outer<String>.Inner obj2 = new Outer<>().new Inner(); // error !
```

The [JLS, section 15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), says this about diamonds:

> A class instance creation expression specifies a class to be
>   instantiated, possibly followed by type arguments (§4.5.1) or a
>   diamond (<>) if the class being instantiated is generic

You have two class instantiation expressions:

```
new Outer<>()
```

and

```
new Inner()  // or more precisely, new Outer<>().new Inner()
```

Towards the end of section 15.9, it distinguishes between these two expressions:

> A class instance creation expression is a poly expression (§15.2) if
>   it uses the diamond form for type arguments to the class, and it
>   appears in an assignment context or an invocation context (§5.2,
>   §5.3). Otherwise, it is a standalone expression.

Thus, the second expression is a poly expression, which means that its type depends on the assignment context; but the first expression, `new Outer<>()`, is a standalone expression: its type is evaluated free from any context.

Your other statement

```
Outer.Inner obj2 = new Outer<>().new Inner();
```

is fine because you are using `Outer` as a raw type.

Comment: This does not explain why the first line in snippet 2 works.

Comment: @Tom and Sweeper thanks for the feedback. You're both right. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to get the code to compile is covered in alfasin's answer.

However, the reason for this is how Java does infer types. Java can only infer a type in certain cases (see documentation for more detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), specifically the section `Target Types`).

Quote from these docs:

> Note: It is important to note that the inference algorithm uses only invocation arguments, target types, and possibly an obvious expected return type to infer types. The inference algorithm does not use results from later in the program.

The problem with your snippets come down to types being inferred by target type inference and the use of the dot operator to chain methods. When using the dot operator, the result of the first method is used for the second method first (gets piped). So this changes the target type so that it is the type expected by following part after the dot. However, only the result of last method in the chain of methods is assigned to the variable type and thus the last method's generic types in your case can be inferred.

So in the first snippet, the part where the type needs to be inferred is the last method after the dot operator, so the target type for this method is the variable to which the result is going to be assigned and thus can be inferred. 
i.e. From your first snippet the line:

```
Outer.Inner<String> obj2 = new Outer().new Inner<>(); // fine !
```

Since 'new Outer()' returns an object that does not have a generic type, no inference need to occur. The second method `new Inner<>()` can continue. The`new Inner<>()` method's result here will be assigned to the variable `obj2` which is declared to have the type `Outer.Inner<String>`, and thus can be inferred from it's target that `T` is to be `String`.

In the second snippet, the part where the type needs to be inferred is the method before the dot operator,  this means that the result of the first method is what the second method is applied to.

So from your second snippet the line:

```
Outer<String>.Inner obj2 = new Outer<>().new Inner();
```

The target type of `new Outer<>()` is what `new Inner()` expects, which is `Outer<T>.newInner()`; Because of Type erasure and how Java generics works, this T, since it is not specified as some specific type is then seen as `Object`. Now the second part can continue, but the result of the second method now ends up being of type `Outer<Object>.Inner`, which can't be converted to the variable's assigned type.

So you need to supply a type witness for the method, i.e. `new Outer<SomeMethod>()`, because it does not have a proper target type in the second snippet to be able to do the type inferencing in the way you want.

Comment: Note that the line `Outer.Inner obj1 = new Outer().new Inner<>(); // fine !` in snippet 2 works, because here `obj1` is declared as a raw type, and the raw type tells the compiler to ignore any type checking of the generic variable `T`. Raw types should be avoided in code, since it can cause many troubles and only exists to be backwards compatible with Java 1.4 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Compile error:

> Error:(11, 50) java: incompatible types:
>   Outer<`java.lang.Object`>.Inner cannot be converted to
>   Outer<`java.lang.String`>.Inner

which means that you should change:

```
Outer<String>.Inner obj2 = new Outer<>().new Inner()
```

to:

```
Outer<String>.Inner obj2 = new Outer<String>().new Inner()
```

The compiler considers `new Outer<>()` as raw type (defaults to Object) while it's expecting `Outer<String>`, hence to resolve it we need to be more specific with the generic type we're providing in the assignment.

Comment: My comments are not applicable anymore :) thus removed